# Custom toolwindowpane for VS Isolated Shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to create some custom tool windows for my isolated shell (VS2010). Below is the code for toolwindow.

```
[Guid("xxxx")]
public class ToolWindow1: ToolWindowPane
{
    public ToolWindow1()
        : base(null)
    {
        this.Caption = "BAM0";
    }
}
```

I am trying to open the tool window via

```
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1))]
...
ToolWindowPane window = this.FindToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1), 0, true);
```

However, I am getting a TargetInvocationException on FindToolWindow call, and I'm not sure why. Am I missing something in displaying a custom tool window?

Thanks!

Edit: my project references weren't set up properly. I ended up merging the two projects, and the tool window is now showing up properly.

Comment: What is the inner exception in the `TargetInvocationException` message?

Comment: Sorry, how can I get the inner exception?

Comment: if you run this under the debugger you can expand the `TargetInvocationException` and see the `InnerException` property

Comment: I can't find how to expand the TargetInvocationException, but I changed some debugger setting and found this:

First-chance exception at 0x77797945 in WPPerfMonShell.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x0061b99c..

Comment: that's unlikely to be the cause.  Try putting a `try / catch` aronud the `FindToolWindow` call and seeing what exception comes out of it.

Comment: Got it. - Could not load file or assembly 'WPPerfMonUserControl, or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified}

Comment: is that your assembly?  If so the most likely problem is the code base isn't registered and it's failing trying to find your tool window type via reflection like APIs